# I don't understand how to return all values in string with return string[i:i+max_width]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I have a code and I wanna return all values in string with newline.

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
for i in range(0, len(string), max_width):
    return string[i:i+max_width]

# You can't change anything here.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

My input

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ
4
```

Required output

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
IMNO
QRST
UVWX
YZ
```

My output

```
ABCD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that you need to run the wrap function n times not just return the value. Also, return breaks the function so it executes only once. One of the correct codes would be:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    temp = ''
    for i in range(0, len(string), max_width):
        temp += f'{string[i:i+max_width]}\n'
    return temp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

Comment: That's great, but see the thing is, in this task I can't modify if __name__ and everything that comes after it. I only need to work with the wrap function

Comment: @lostonthecoderoad I have edited the code according to your requirements